# vueHtml2Pdf download pdf blank page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hello I'm new in vueHtml2Pdf my issues is vueHtml2Pdf generate my page is good but when i ckick button download is download blank page.

my code generated pdf but the preview modal is blank and the donwload

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="downloadPdf">
      Print Download
    </button>

    <vue-html2pdf
      ref="html2Pdf"
      :show-layout="true"
      :float-layout="true"
      :enable-download="true"
      :preview-modal="true"
      filename="hee hee"
      :pdf-quality="2"
      :paginate-elements-by-height="1400"
      :manual-pagination="false"
      pdf-format="a4"
      pdf-orientation="landscape"
      pdf-content-width="800px"
      pdf-unit="in"
    >
      <section slot="pdf-content">
        <p> test my pdf</p>
        <p> my pdf </p>
      </section>
    </vue-html2pdf>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHtml2pdf from 'vue-html2pdf';
export default {
 components: {
    VueHtml2pdf
  },
  methods: {
    async downloadPdf () {
      this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and i have this error in my console

Warning: Invalid absolute docBaseUrl: "blob:https://localhost:8080/9c98ebc9-2707-4b30-a504-99ff262f0e01"

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Add your content inside another `<section>` tag.

---

I recently did work with this library, and this is my base component that renders different content (code below).

The only real difference I see between our code might be the `await` on the function that generates the PDF.

Try that, but if it doesn't work, you might try and copy paste my code below and see if it works (Just replace the `<slot/>` with whatever you want, and add some boilerplate for the props).

```
<template>
    <div class="pdf-converter">
        <BaseButton
            class="mt-auto text-white h-13 bg-blue"
            :disabled="disableButton"
            @click="$emit('generate-pdf')"
        >
            {{ buttonText }}
        </BaseButton>
        <VuePDF
            ref="html2pdf"
            :show-layout="false"
            :float-layout="false"
            :enable-download="false"
            preview-modal
            :paginate-elements-by-height="1400"
            pdf-content-width="700px"
            :filename="fileName"
            :manual-pagination="false"
            pdf-format="a4"
            :html-to-pdf-options="pdfOptions"
        >
            <section
                slot="pdf-content"
            >
                <div
                    v-if="show"
                >
                    <slot />
                </div>
            </section>
        </VuePDF>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import VuePDF from 'vue-html2pdf'

export default {
    name: 'BasePdfConverter',
    components: { VuePDF },
    props: {
        disableButton: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        buttonText: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Generate Report'
        },
        fileName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        reportToWatch: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: true
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            show: false,
            pdfOptions: {
                margin: [10, 2, 10, 2], // top, left, buttom, right
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 2,
                    bottom: 20
                },
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: 'mm',
                    orientation: 'portrait'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getLoaderState'])
    },
    watch: {
        '$store.state.ReportsModule.reports': {
            handler: async function (newVal) {
                if (Object.keys(newVal[this.reportToWatch]).length) {
                    this.show = true
                    await this.$refs.html2pdf.generatePdf()
                    this.show = false
                } else {
                    this.$showAlert({
                        message: 'No data available for this job',
                        type: 'error'
                    })
                }
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank riza i add ``` await ``` in my function generate is not work i add your code is not work

Comment: @francky I think I know what your problem is. I'll update my answer. Basically, wrap your content inside another `<section>` tag

Comment: @razi i wrap my content in another section like this `<section slot="pdf-content"><section>test value</section></section>`  it still does not work